# Has the acoustic version of Unravel been released yet?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

The last song that plays while kaneki's holding hide in his arms while walking through whithout looking back, right at the last scene of the last episode... (which I believe it's an acoustic version of unravel, if my memory isn't tricking me). Has it been released yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the song you are looking for. [Tokyo Ghoul - Unravel (Acoustic)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jA4GvMtHhs).

If you want to purchase it, here is the link to the Apple iTunes page: [unravel (acoustic version) - Single, by TK from 凛として時雨](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/album/unravel-acoustic-version-single/id992699090)